# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse to fold the current method/block?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

question says it all.
I have folding turned on in Eclipse (v3.4), and rather than having to click the little +/- in the page gutter, I'm wondering if there's a keyboard shortcut to just: *fold the current method*.

A quick look at the menus and what-not in eclipse doesn't show a menu item for it, so maybe you just can't do it.

Anyone?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

By default they're bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Minus</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Plus</kbd>, but you can rebind them.

Comment: @petrilli   What is Numpad_plus on macbook pro?  I don't have a number keypad.

Comment: Some laptops have a virtual numpad if you use the FN or NumLock key. I don't think macs have that, so you're better off just rebinding the keys to something else.

Answer (score 129):

To expand on petrilli's answer:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Multiply</kbd> can also be used to expand all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Divide</kbd> is bound to collapse all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Divide</kbd> toggles folding on and off

And yes, they can all be rebound, if you know what text to filter on in Windows | Preferences | General | Keys.

"Folding", "Expand", "Collapse" are keywords that should get you all of the relevant commands.

Comment: NOTE: If you don't see the "-"s/"+"s on blocks, then "folding" is disabled. Rt-Click on the gutter (where you would normally see those "+"s), select "Folding > Enable Folding".  (Here you will also see the keyboard shortcuts for the various folding actions.) `Ctrl`+`Numpad_Divide` is the shortcut to toggle enable folding on/off. This is annoying, because that is easy to do by accident instead of `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Numpad_Divide`, which is what you often want to do when you open a file, to collapse everything, to see the overall structure.

Comment: So it appears that I had folding disabled.

If anyone needs to enable folding under the version of Eclipse I was using it could be found under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using eclipse-pydev then the default keybinds are

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> : collapse all one level

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> : expand all one level

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-_</kbd> : collapse current location

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=+</kbd> : expand current

Comment: Not on a Mac, apparently.

Comment: These don't appear to be the default bindings for PyDev on Windows anymore.