# Is there a way to collapse all code blocks in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Eclipse has that "+/-" on the left to expand and collapse blocks of code.

I've got tens of thousands of lines to go through and would really like to just collapse everything, and selectively expand blocks to look at them.

Comment: Check also this thread:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450880/how-to-collapse-blocks-of-code-in-eclipse

Comment: How about collapsing just the code and not the comments? I guess I could generate a javadoc but still it would be nice

Comment: Eclipse has tons of options. Considering your purpose, Ctrl+O (ctrl and letter O) might be the most practical. It allows selecting and jumping to specific blocks.

Comment: If your keyboard doesn't have numpad, check [akf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726549/606662).

Comment: Key binding is different for Eclipse Neon on Linux. To check key binding for you version on eclipse on your OS, check under Preferences->General->Keys. or search for "keys" in Preferences. Then look for "Collapse All" and "Expand All"

Answer (score 891, accepted):

There is a hotkey, mapped by default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd>.

You can change it to something else via Window -> Preferences, search for "Keys", then for "Collapse All".

To open all code blocks the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd>.

In the Eclipse extension *PyDev*, close all code blocks is 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>

To open all blocks, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: You might be interested in the opposite shortcut 'expand all' as well.Ctrl + Shift + *

Comment: Is there a command for inverting collapsed/expanded state, so I can just press same key combination and it'd expand or collapse it depending on the current state of the code block? Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, it seems like this shortcut (no matter what you bind it to) doesn't work for PyDev. If someone reads this and knows the opposite to be true, please post otherwise!

Comment: I found it insanely unreasonable that the developers of Eclipse didn't implement this into the Menu.

Comment: I just wanted to say that another way is to right-click the narrow vertical bar has has all of the (+)/(-) little pluses and minuses. The option to fold the code will be there.

Comment: @seafangs PyDev has its own bindings for this stuff. Collapse all is ctrl+9 by default. See here: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html

Comment: Hi @ChssPly76, Can you create Headers in Eclipse? Like in Xcode where you can easily navigate through your code by clicking the pragma mark?

Comment: Expanding code blocks in Zend Eclipse PDT is set to `Ctrl`+`*` by default. Note: There's no `Shift` involved.

Comment: Just in case anyone is using OS X, it is Cmd + Shift + / for Collapse All; and, Cmd + Shift + * for Expand All :) Pretty obvious, but just making sure :)

Comment: Is there a way to hide these blocks? I want to see just the current block, nothing else more. And then, pressing F3 on other methods, I want to go to method "unhide" it. I know that is too much, but I like to see clearly in what I am working.

Comment: Hint: the command that gets invoked is `Toggle Folding`. (if you don't have a number keypad because you're using a Macbook then add the binding as just `Shift + Cmd +5`)

Comment: In Eclispe Neon with PyDev, it is now CTRL + numpad divide

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY. not working on eclipse neon IDE. Instead of that Ctrl+NUM_KEYPAD_MULTIPLY. worked fine to open all brackets

Comment: In Aptana studio which uses Eclipse extension, works only with the first solution to Collapse with (Ctrl+Shift+NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE). Does not work with other options to open the Collapsed items.

Comment: If these shortcuts don't work for you, it could be because you have folding disabled. To enable folding, the shortcut is `Ctrl`+`Numpad_Divide`

Comment: while working on a laptop .. its good to change this key to something else .. or use context menu as per akf's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726549/3509609.

Comment: If it didn't work,  closing the current file tab then reopening it could solve the problem.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>++<kbd>NUM\_KEYPAD\_MULTIPLY</kbd> alone if you really want to expand all, imports included. (With the shift key it doesn't expand import which is exactly want I was looking for).

Comment: this not working in my version Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Answer (score 151):

In addition to the hotkey, if you right click in the gutter where you see the +/-, there is a context menu item 'Folding.'  Opening the submenu associated with this, you can see a 'Collapse All' item.  this will also do what you wish.

Comment: Use fn and divide that is being called when fn button is pressed

Comment: Nice one - there is also the possibility to collapse comments only!

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + * wasn't working on my Eclipse Java EE Indigo; 
thank you

Comment: In eclipse 3.8 with PyDev 4.1 the gutter has no 'Folding' option in the context menu

Comment: You can actually click anywhere in the left hand gutter (breakpoints, line numbers, `+/-`). This makes it easier than trying to aim for a tiny `+/-`

Answer (score 29):

A "Collapse All" command exists in recent builds (e.g. 3.2 M6) and is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd> by default.

You can also configure it in Preferences->Editor->Keys.

Comment: Could you please tell me for mac ?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal Instead of Ctrl, the button is Command, so: Command + Shift + NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE on Mac. Tested myself just now. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340049/how-do-i-collapse-all-in-eclipse-on-macbook

Answer (score 11):

The question is a bit old, but let me add a different approach.  In addition to the above hot-key approaches, there are default preference settings that can be toggled.

As of Eclipse Galileo (and definitely in my Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857) language specific preferences can open up new files to edit which are already collapsed or expanded.

Here is a link to Eclipse Galileo online docs showing the feature for C/C++:  http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_editor_folding.htm .

In my Eclipse Indigo I can open the Folding Preferences window via : `menu/ Window/ Preferences/ Java/ Editor/ Folding` and set all options on so I can open files by default that are completely collapsed.

Answer (score 11):

If you always want the code collapsed by default, go to Windows > Preferences. Search for "folding". Then check all the items under "Initially fold these elements".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Folding was disabled by default for me.

Comment: I agree noitib, thanks you ! that's perfect :)

Answer (score 9):

Right click on the +/- sign and click collapse all or expand all.

Comment: Which does not work for the PyDev extension, as of 4.1

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> works great for Aptana Studio 3.

Apart from that you can always use Window > Preferences > Editors > Foldings to enable it

Answer (score 6):

Just to sum up:

1. anycode:

   - ctrl + shift + NUMPAD_divide = collapse all
   - NUMPAD_multiply = exand all
2. pydev:

   - -ctrl + 0 = collapse all
   - -ctrl + 9 = exand all

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PyDev in Eclipse, its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> for collapse all and uncollapse all respectively. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to collapse individual methods when your cursor is on the line of the method declaration.

Comment: In PyDev, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> collapses and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> uncollapses all code blocks. A list of common PyDev shortcuts can be found [at pydev's website](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html).

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the circles +/- sign and under Foldings select Collapse All

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found out Folding can be enabled or disabled, and in my case got disabled somehow.

To solve it, simply right click on the line numbers/breakpoint section (vertical bar in the left of the editor), then under the 'Folding' section chose 'Enable folding'.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> should be working fine after.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts that worked for me in *Versions Oxygen.2 Release* (**PHP/WINDOWS 7**) were

1. **Collapse all** code blocks: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD_DIVIDE</kbd>
2. **Expand all** code blocks : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I noticed few things:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> toggles Folding-enabled or -disabled.

It is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> that expands. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> collapses just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have a separate numpad, you can activate the overlapping numpad using the number lock- this varies with the type of keypad-> **fn** + **numlk**  for hp

then try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>numpad_Divide</kbd>

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Collapse all  : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Expand all code blocks : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

i was using lapop numpad  was orange color which will get enable using function (Fn) button ...so try

shift + crtl + fn + (see where is divide)
in my case its on 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Keys are not working for me but there is pane where row nos are written, RC -> Folding-> Collapse and Expand option is present you can use them.

let me know if you find this answer interesting :-)
Happy learning.