# How to collapse blocks of code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-editor

Some days ago my Eclipse was working fine and a +/- appeared in every block that could be collapsed (functions, classes, etc.)... but now it does appear, and I don't know how to activate that feature again.

It's Eclipse Helios, running on a Gentoo Linux box.

Comment: In Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Folding there is a checkbox: "Enable folding of control flow statements". You may not see anything immediately because computing the fold points may happen slowly in the background, or it may be necessary to invoke the "Reset Structure" command shift+ctrl+numpad_multiply, to get eclipse to show all the fold points.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Folding ?

Make a right click in the editor window and go to preferences there, then only the editor-relevant section of the preferences dialog will appear. This works for JDT, CDT etc...

Comment: Another way is to right-click the narrow vertical bar has has all of the (+)/(-) little pluses and minuses. The option to fold the code will be there.

Comment: In current Eclipse, I do not see any "Folding" option under editor for each language. Instead, @KennyPeng's answer is what works for me.

Answer (score 61):

You can do ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Divide</kbd> ) to enable folding.
Also if you `Right Click` on the area where the `+` or `-` was supposed to be, you can see there is a folding option.

Comment: That option is selected and working but I want folding for If/else and  switch cases... How can I get that ?

Comment: C + S + Num / - does a collapse all. I had accidentally hit C + / - and voila no more code folding. Thanks this helped to get it back!

Answer (score 19):

Try this option: Preferences > Java > Editor > Folding > Enable folding

Answer (score 15):

To collapse all code blocks
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>/</kbd>

To expand all code blocks
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>*</kbd>

**pydev:**

To collapse all code blocks : 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

To collapse all code blocks : 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>

[Is there a way to collapse all code blocks in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726525/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-code-blocks-in-eclipse)

by @partizanos and @bummi

Answer (score 11):

For Python it is as follows:

- collapse all 1 level: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
- expand all 1 level: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
- collapse current: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- expand current: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

In Preferences, you'll find General > Keys.  It's for setting your keyboard shortcuts.

What I use it for more often, though, is to find stuff in Eclipse.  You should see an input box labelled "type filter text."  It's as close as Eclipse comes to a search feature for every Eclipse command.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Java, but look under the settings for your particular language.

Under the Window menu, select Preferences.

Under Java->Editor->Folding. Select "Enable Folding".

Comment: That option is selected and working but I want folding for If/else and  switch cases... How can I get that ?

Comment: @Amit as far as i know, you can't.

Comment: In Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Folding there is a checkbox: "Enable folding of control flow statements".

Comment: Computing the fold points may happen slowly in the background, or it may be necessary to invoke the "Reset Structure" command shift+ctrl+numpad_multiply, to get eclipse to show all the fold points.

Answer (score 1):

If you want folding an all your editors, I found you can enable Folding in

Preferences > Editors > Structured Text Editors

Enable Folding

Answer (score 1):

For windows eclipse using java: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding

Unfortunately this will not allow for collapsing code, however if it turns off you can re-enable it to get rid of long comments and imports.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

1. Right Click on + button appeared on numbering strip on left most side --> Folding --> Expand All
2. Right Click on + button appeared on numbering strip on left most side --> Folding --> Collapse All

This way you can expand and collapse all the methods on the file.

[Plus Buttons on numbering strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxrTK.png)

Context Menu:

[Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcVLY.png)

Answer (score 0):

In CFEclipse:
Preferences > CFEclipse > Editor > Code Folding >  Initially Collapse column, you can uncheck to see all expanded when opening, or check all boxes to close all when opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

I was using salesforce apex classes with Eclipse Neon 3.3 for Java.
 I found an option "**define folding region**" on right click in the editor, I selected the block of code i wanted to collapse and selected this property for that code. Now I am seeing + and - symbol to expand and collapse that block of code