# Expand and collapse blocks of code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor, expand

Having to read lots of legacy code to check what it makes and get a bigger picture.

Is there any way to expand / collapse blocks of code in eclipse, 
like

`+ if {...}` or

`+ else {...}`

I already saw those SO on the topic

[ide fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369057/is-there-a-way-to-fold-eclipse-sub-blocks-like-an-if-statement)

[how to collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450880/how-to-collapse-blocks-of-code-in-eclipse)

[and this eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174597)

but they are quite old, perhaps there is a solution available now.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726525/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-code-blocks-in-eclipse

Comment: Oh, I already saw this, but did not mention it in the question. This does not work for if and else specifically.