# Eclipse how to fold a block of code that is neither function nor structure?

Tags: c++, eclipse, code-folding

Is it possible to fold blocks of C++ code in Eclpise (neon). With the default folding options functions, structures, etc are nicely folded, but blocks of code cannot be folded, eg.

```
void foo(){              // <- can be folded
     ...
}

void bar(){
     ...
     {                  // <- cannot be folded
         ....
     }
}
```

In the preferences there is a option to "Select folding to use" and the [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_editor_folding.htm) claim that I could choose among the available choices, but there is only a single option: Default C Folding.

**How can I enable folding for blocks of code that are no functions or structures?**

PS: [This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450880/how-to-collapse-blocks-of-code-in-eclipse) title is actually exactly what I am looking for... How to fold **blocks** of code. However, the answers are only explaining how to enable folding.

Comment: I was looking for the same feature in Eclipse but apparently, it depends on the C/C++ plugin which installed and the classic one (CDT) doesn't have any option to make code blocks folded.