# Keeping Code Collapsed - Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Just curious if there's a setting somewhere in Eclipse to keep blocks of code collapsed when the class is opened? It's just I'll collapse methods then when the class is re-opened, everything is expanded.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the awesome replies all. Shame I can't mark all your comments as the answer.

Comment: It may  be helpful for you i guess.

Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `Windows` > `preferences`:

`Java` > `editor` > `folding`: check all, click `apply` & then `OK`.

Maybe this helps: `Ctrl` + `Shift`+ `NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE` collapse all methods in a java class.

[image: Eclipse Source Code Folding]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726525/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-code-blocks-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 13):

Yes . From the [eclipse official documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html#navigation_section) :

> You can specify which regions are folded by default when an editor is
>   opened. Have a look at the Opens the folding preference page **Java >Editor > Folding** 
>   preference page to customize this.
>
> [image]

Just click all the checkboxs .Then whenever a .java file is open in the java editor  , everything will be collapsed.

Not sure if this options is the new feature for eclipse indigo version (3.7) , so you may have to update your eclipse to indigo if you use older version but cannot find this option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a solution, but let me tell you how I work - maybe this is a solution for you as well:

1. Enable **"Only show the selected Java element"**. The editor will only show the element (method) you selected (see screenshot).
2. While editing a file use either the **Outline** view or `CTRL + O` to navigate through the class file.

Btw: I disabled all folding options as the above approach just works best for me. Sadly, I'm not aware of a shortcut to enable/disable the "Only show the selected Java element".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the options what to fold on file open.

You can find it at **Settings->Editor->Folding**

It features a resonable selection of folding options.