# How do I "collapse all" in Eclipse on MacBook?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I run Eclipse on a MacBook. I want to use keyboard to collapse all functions, so I pull out the cheat sheet and found that I have to press some key and the "Numpad_Substract", which is not available on MacBook's keyboard. What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

You can edit the preferences of the hot-keys.
Just go to Eclipse ==> Preferences ==> Keys.
There you can search for "collapse all" and change the key-mapping.

Comment: eclipse mars dont have this option, where is it?

Comment: @fguespe : It is still there. The option "Keys" is now under "General". The "Collapse all" is there like before.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard ShortCut from Eclipse:

⇧⌘Numpad_Divide

Comment: But MacBooks don't have a numpad ?

Answer (score 0):

Open settings (you can use command **⌘,**) then search **Keys** from search bar in setting page.

Again in search bar inside all keys shortcut settings, you'll see *type filter text*, now type there *COLLAPSE ALL*. Here you can add your shortcut as per your convenience. In the Binding section, do change your hot key.

Here is my setting for your reference.[image: keys setting to collapse all code in eclipse in MacBook]

Do note that in corresponding **category** I kept *editing java source* and *editing text.*

You can do similar for **EXPANDING ALL** methods in your Java code which you just collapsed. Attaching my setting for reference.
[image]