# Eclipse shortcut for minimize / expand method has stopped working

Tags: eclipse

I'm using the [shortcuts to expand / minimize methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726537/400284) quite a lot. For some reason all of these have suddenly (after starting Eclipse this morning) stopped working, and I'm a bit dumbfounded as to why. All other shortcuts (at least that I know of, and have tested) work just fine.

I've attempted to restart Eclipse and checked the error logs (nothing there).

Running latest (stable, not RC) Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Check `Preferences`=>`General`=>`Keys`. There you should be able to see if a shortcut is assigned and assign it if it isn't or is the wrong one.

Comment: I had the same issue a couple of days ago and I almost got desperate. The thing was that I accidentally changed the "Scheme" at the top of the "Keys" properties dialog to "Emacs" instead of "Default"...

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+L to check the shortcut, collapse/expand shortcut is CTRL + Nimpad_minus and CTRL + Numpad_Add, check numlock, also check your system(ubuntu) maybe you assign a custom shortcut for CTRL + Numpad_minus/add

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns outs it was a very simple (and stupid) fix: I had accidentally hit CTRL + numpad_Divide, this toggles "Folding" which in turn determines if it's possible to expand / minimize methods.

Comment: In intelliJ works CTRL+ / for collapse all method, but it don't expande all if you repeate that. @KG Christensen

Comment: Thank you, that's been driving me crazy.