# Keeping code folded in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, folding

If I close Eclipse and then reopen it sometime later, all the code I have folded will be unfolded.

Is there a way to keep it folded?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I just realised it was typo'd. xD

Comment: This has been asked/answered already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115653/eclipse-save-folding-on-quit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

- `Ctrl + Shift + /` to fold your editor code.
- `Ctrl + Shift + *` to unfold your editor code.

Note: Here `* and /` would be on Numeric Keypad

Answer (score 3):

It actually **depends on the the feature** you're using. For Java you can specify which parts should stay folded initially. Unfortunately it only can be comments, header comments, inner types, members and imports.

Here is the screenshot from Eclipse workspace properties for Java > Editor > Folding

[image]