# code unfolded if file is opened in pydev eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

If I fold the code of a file (.py, pydev eclipse) and than save the file and reopen it, the code of the file is unfolded. I would like to know if eclipse can be set to show folded code when file is reopened?

Comment: Can you please explain clearly what you're after? At the moment it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Using pydev in eclipse I have created a file and due to easier scrolling I have manually folded the code of every function in a file. Than I save andclose the file and open it again, but the folded code is unfolded when  file is opened. I would like to know why is code automatically unfolded. I hope I have clearly described my "problem". I would found it more practical if the code would be folded when the file is opened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Save Folding on Quit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115653/eclipse-save-folding-on-quit)